# Is this question a good fit for the site?

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing the Triage and saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625457/how-to-use-dictionary-to-edit-asp-net-mvc). At the very least it needs editing, so I selected that, but It kept bugging me.

It seems too generic, like he could check how dictionary works on C# on MSDN or something. But I don't know what the correct reason to close it would be. Or what actions I should take to deal with it (improve it, close it, etc).

Is this question a good fit?

Note: I couldn't find any duplicates.

Comment: _Too broad_, I'd say. Or even _unclear_.

Comment: Questions that boil down to "I have these ideas whirring around in my head which I have not properly researched, here let me dump them in the hope someone can complete my thought" don't make for very good questions, that's for sure. The best-guess answers strengthen that. I gravitate towards "unclear".

Comment: The question is deleted now.

Comment: Note that if you're unsure of how to handle a post you should really ask *before* acting on that post, rather than taking an action that you are unsure of and *then* asking people about it.  It's less important in Triage than other queues because you can just go back to the question and vote/flag for closure, but still not ideal.  For example, if you had succeeded in sending this question to the HI queue, when it wasn't really salvageable, you'd have been wasting reviewers' time there.

Comment: @Servy yes you are right I am sorry about that. At first sight I could see it needed editing, so I selected that, although it bothered me, I felt I was maybe being too picky since there were other users answering the OP. But then the more I thought about it, the more I was unsure. So I asked here. In the future I will do as you say, I will ask instead of taking action. Thanks!

Comment: @Dzyann The important thing to realize is that "needs editing" doesn't mean, "someone could make an edit to this post", but rather, "after some community member takes the time to edit all of the problems that they can fix with this post, it will be a good question."  After all, we don't want to be polishing turds.  If there are things for some to edit, *but fixing them won't turn the question into an acceptable question*, then you need to be marking it as unsalvageable, not needing editing.

Comment: I often edit a question to make it properly formatted and *then* vote to close because it’s still bad but to make it easier for others to focus on the content instead of the formatting… (and to aid OP in case they end up improving the question)

Comment: @Dzyann Next time please add a screenshot of the question or something so in case it gets deleted (as happened now) your question still makes sense.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto if you ask in a comment there is usually a willing and able 10k+ (or 20k+?) user that will post a screenshot of the deleted question. All is not lost of something ends up deleted after the fact.

Comment: I was hoping the question referred to this actual question. Was excited to finally see something that belongs in `Meta-Meta`.